# How to convert code from node.js to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to rewrite an Api call. The original call is write in Node.js and i'm trying to rewrite the call in Javascript.
Node.js code:

```
const http = require("https");

const options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "test.com",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/path",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Token token-value"
  }
};

const req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  const chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({
  data: {
    'Id': 'id value'
  },
  responsive: false
}));
req.end();
```

I'm trying in this way:

```
const url='https://test.com/path'

    const bodyContent = {
        data: {
            'Id': 'id value'
        },
        responsive: false
    };   
    const options = {
        "method":"POST",
        "port":null,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization":"Token token-value"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyContent)
    }
    const res = await fetch(url, options)
```

I expected a positive response but the response keep saying "Missing value of required parameter 'Id'"

Comment: Node.js is not a language, it is a JavaScript interpreter and environment. A browser is also a JavaScript interpreter and a (different) environment. "Converting" the code from Node.js to JavaScript does not make any sense. The code already is written in JavaScript.

Comment: How do you want to run this code? In a browser?

Comment: @axiac i think they want to call the api in the frontend

Comment: @axiac yes i need to run this code in browser

Comment: There definitely is a fundamental lack of understanding regarding what Node & Javascript truely are. To add to other comments, Node is what will run instructions you wrote in a JavaScript file, it's built as a server-side interpreter and comes with tools & community built add-ons to allow us to do that efficiently. Your browser (google/edge/firefox) use its own interpreter which does not have the same tools, add-ons , purpose or capabilities. You're using fetch to make a request to the server, this is one way to do it, but we need more context regarding the error you get.

Comment: @xoxel i'm tryng to do a chrome extension. The plugin runs on notion.so, it makes a call to make.com for run a scenario. I get a 400 with this message 
"Missing value of required parameter 'Id'." from make.com

Comment: You are passing `data.Id`, not `Id`. Is that your problem?